# Why xUnit tests are not turning into green?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tdd, xunit

I am using ***visual studio 17 version 15.9.19*** on windows os. Created a ***xUnit*** Test project (.Net Core) targeting framework is ***.Net Core 2.2***.

I added all the necessary ***nuget packages*** everything looks good tests discovered in test explorer.

The following packages I added

```
xunit v2.4.1
xunit.core v2.4.1
xunit.extensibility.core v2.4.1
xunit.runner.console v2.4.1
xunit.runner.visualstudio v2.4.1
```

Test settings default processor architecture is ***X64***, under Project's properties CPU is set to ***X64***.

Multiple time I ***restarted VS17 and runs under administrator***. However, tests are not passing neither failing. What is going exactly I can't figure out.

I spent massive time on internet to find the solution and applied but still issue not resolved.

So, I am looking some help that Why xUnit tests are not turning into green or even red? I am not using Resharper.

***Any help to resolve this issue would be appreciated***.
Thanks

One important thing tests are passing or failing using dotnet test command on command prompt.

Comment: _I added all the necessary nuget packages_ - can you show us the list of packages you added?

Comment: Are they being detected as tests? Can you show a simple example of one of your tests.